# How to refresh TableView Cell data during an NSTimer loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

Disclaimer: I'm a new convert to iOS, so please feel free to tell me that my whole approach is wrong. I only ask that you explain why -- my goal here is to learn (and, of course, also to solve this problem).

...

Hi all, I'm new to iOS programming and after trying to solve this problem for several hours, my ignorance and cocoa inexperience is getting the best of me. Hoping I can find some help here.

I've got a simple TableView App I'm working on as a sandbox for a larger app that's in the works. The functionality I'm trying to achieve right now is a pseudo real-time update of the subtitle text in a TableView Cell (i.e. cell.detailTextLabel.text ).

To give you a better idea of the goal: I'm trying to make it so the user can tap the TableView cell and a "stopwatch" style timer starts counting up in the subtitle text.

But I can't figure out how to update cell.detailTextLabel.text either A) From inside my timer methods (it says tableView undeclared) and B) In a way that refreshes the cell repeatedly so the user sees an "active" timer.

So, here's some code (all of this is in RootViewController right now. Eventually I'll want to make separate classes for functions like the timer, but I just want to get things working first).

I should also add that I've got a lot of global ("interface?") variables in this class right now. It makes it easier to experiment, but if that could be causing some of the problems please let me know. I'm still learning how to pass objects/variables/etc back and forth.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    self.runTimerFunctions;
}
```

Then the timer function (those are interface variables):

```
- (void) runTimerFunctions {

    start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    timerRunning = YES;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  
}
```

The math and calculation itself. Results in a single string "liveTimer" of the format MM:SS.hh that accurately "stopwatches" upward:

```
- (void)targetMethod: (NSTimer *)theTimer {

    // NOTE TO SELF -- right now I've got hours, minutes, seconds, etc as global variables. But that may be unnecessary.

    CFAbsoluteTime end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    CFAbsoluteTime timeDelta = end-start;
    int integerSecs = timeDelta;
    int integerCentiSecs = timeDelta * 100;

    hundredths = integerCentiSecs % 100;
    NSString *hundredthsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", hundredths];

    seconds = integerSecs % 60;
    NSString *secondsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", seconds];

    minutes = (integerSecs / 60) % 60;
    NSString *minutesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", minutes];

    // Now combine these value strings into the single liveTimer string

    liveTimer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString];

}
```

Okay, so the liveTimer string is an interface variable so I can modify it and access it throughout (this may not be the way to do this, again I'm a noob so please correct me wherever necessary).

In the initial UITableViewCell creation bit, I use liveTimer for the detail text value, as follows:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
NSLog(@"liveTimer value is %@", liveTimer);
cell.detailTextLabel.text = liveTimer;
```

So essentially, the way I have things right now, when the user presses the list item, the timer starts counting *in the background* (I've confirmed with NSLog that it's working correctly -- if I extract liveTimer at the end of targetMethod it's correctly formatted and counting upward.

But how do I reflect this via a pseudo real-time update of the cell text?

[tableView reloadData] keeps crashing the program (without error code) when I put it anywhere I can, but I don't know how to access it from targetMethod (it tells me tableView undeclared when I add [tableView reloadData] ).

Further, [tableView reloadData] keeps crashing the program (without error message) even when I try to drop it experimentally into, say, didSelectRowAtIndexPath. e.g.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    self.runTimerFunctions;

    [tableView reloadData];
```

Essentially I'm sure there's a simple way to do what I'm trying to do, but I'm still too new to the language to know how to do it. I wouldn't be surprised if I'm overloading the system by trying to call reloadData during the timer loop. But then again, maybe it's something else.

Any advice would be much appreciated. I'm trying to learn the language here so, although sample code is extremely helpful, I'm equally interested in "learning how to fish", so I'd really appreciate explanations of *why* what I'm doing is wrong and what the better ways to do it might be, etc.

Thanks in advance for all your help; I'm looking forward to getting involved on the forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a small bug...

`liveTimer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString];`

This is probably why it was crashing when you called reload tableView.

You actually want:

either:

```
self.liveTimer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString];
```

(if you've configured liveTimer to be a property and not just a member variable)

or

```
[liveTimer release];
liveTimer = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString] retain];
```

or

```
[liveTimer release];
liveTimer = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString];
```

`stringWithFormat:...` returns an auto-released string, which means that it gets released as at the end of the current spin through the run loop.  This will result in liveTimer pointing at undefined memory essentially after your function finishes.  Using self.liveTimer instead of liveTimer causes your synthesized setter method to be called instead of just setting the variable directly, which causes your object to retain the string as it's being set (assuming you've setup the live timer property to retain, like so: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *liveTimer;`  The other two alternatives listed above both release the old version of the string and then retain the new string and set then set the variable directly.  Which one you prefer between the first and the last is more or less a matter of taste, the second one is kind of silly (it roundaboutly creates the string, autoreleases it, and then retains it again.)

Now, on to your question.

At the end of `- (void)targetMethod: (NSTimer *)theTimer`, you'll want to actually update the current table cell, if it exisits.  Assume the tableCell exists at row 0 of section 0:

```
-(void)targetMethod: (NSTimer *)theTimer {    

    // Everything you already had here, then...

    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
    // Returns the cell that's currently in the tableview at this location

    currentCell.detailTextLabel.text = self.liveTimer;
}
```

That should do it... if the current cell doesn't exist (because it's scrolled off the screen) `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will return nil, and `currentCell.detailTextLabel.text = self.liveTimer;` will do nothing (i.e. no error, just literally nothing).

Edit:

I just noticed that tableView is not one of your object member variables...

Do you have a `UITableViewController` hanging around that you can get to?  If so, just use `tableViewControllerVariableName.tableView` everywhere you presently use tableView.  Is your RootViewController (which all this code is in) a UITableViewController? If so call `self.tableView` wherever you currently call tableView.  If not, where is your tableView/tableViewController being allocated?  Posting your header file might help clear things up...

**Edit 2:**

The issue with liveTimer vs. self.liveTimer is all about the retain count on the object.

```
liveTimer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString];
```

does just what it looks like--it sets your liveTimer variable to the new string.  Whereas

```
self.liveTimer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString];
```

is a little bit magic.  Using the `self.` prefix (or, for that matter `anyObject.`) tells the compiler "what I really want to do here is call the accessor method for the liveTimer property".  The compiler essentially replaces the above line with:

```
[self setLiveTimer:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@.%@", minutesString, secondsString, hundredthsString]];
```

Because you presumably have `@synthesize liveTimer;` somewhere in your class file, the compiler also creates the `-(void)setLiveTimer:(NSTimer *)timer` and `-(NSTimer *)liveTimer` methods for you automatically.  They looks something like this:

```
-(void)setLiveTimer:(NSTimer *)newLiveTimer
{
    [liveTimer release];  // This is the old value.  It may be nil, which is fine.  Calling methods on nil objects in objective-c is just be a noop, not a crash.
    liveTimer = [newLiveTimer retain];
}

-(NSTimer *)liveTimer
{
    return liveTimer;
}
```

(This is a bit of an over-simplification, but that's the important stuff.)

So, when you call `self.liveTimer`, the `setLiveTimer:` method gets called with the object, the old object, if any, gets released, and the new object gets retained.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` returns an autoreleased object.  Autoreleased objects get released after control returns from the program's code to the apple-supplied run-loop code.  They are more or less a convenience so we don't have to `release` all the little objects that we use once or twice here and there.  (For example, imagine how tedious it would be if you had to release every string you created with the @"" syntax...)

We can tell `stringWithFormat:` returns an autoreleased object because, by convention, methods who's names don't start with `alloc` or `copy` always return auto-released objects.  Methods like this are said to "vend" an object.  We can use these objects in the immediate future, but we don't "own" it (i.e. we can't count on it being there after we return control to the system.)  If we want to take ownership of a vended object, we have to call `[object retain]` on it, and then it will be there until we explicitly call `[object release]` or `[object autorelease]`, and if we don't call `release` or `autorelease` on it before we lose our reference to it by changing the variable to something else, we will leak it.

Contrast with `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:`.  This method "creates" an object.  We own it.  Again, it will be there until we explicitly call `[object release]`.

So, you were setting the member variable `liveTimer` to a new string, but that string was auto-released, and as soon as your `- (void)targetMethod: (NSTimer *)theTimer` returned, control returned to the system's run-loop code, and that string was getting released.  That meant that liveTimer pointed to some random spot in memory that at one point had contained your string object, but now contained something else--something undefined.  When you called a method on that random spot in memory it, it crashed.

(To confuse things further, `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:]` is a special case.  The timer retains itself until it fires, which is why that part of your code works.  Nobody really knows why NSTimer gets an exception; it's confusing as hell. It's left over from the NExT days--code written in the early 90s when it seemed like a good idea to someone.)

So, do you want to use `self.liveTimer` or `self.timer`, or `self.whatever` everywhere? More or less.  You normally want to retain the new object and release the old.  <strike>The only</strike> One of the many exceptions is that if you "create" an object with `[[Object alloc] init]`, that object comes to you with a retain count of 1 already, in that case, using the `self.` syntax will retain the object a second time, which is probably not what you want.  (Although, if you've set `self.liveTimer =` before and you then use `liveTimer =` later in your code, the first string will be leaked, because nothing ever released it.  It's not always trivial, deciding which way to do it.)

Hope that clears things up a little.  This dotted notation stuff in objective-c is the least intuitive part of the language, I think.  Be sure to read apple's document on memory management:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html

Comment: Hi Peter, I appreciate your taking the time to respond. I'll take a look at this later today and also post my header files. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, so I took a look at your feedback Peter and things are working now. Thanks! I still don't fully understand what I did, so I have a few questions. 

First, do I replace "liveTimer" with "self.liveTimer" *literally* everywhere it appears? I've done this but am not sure if I should have. It's working though.

Second, liveTimer was a property, so your first comment worked there.

Comment: Finally, regarding your viewController question. This is a UITableViewController, so (as mentioned) self.tableView seems to have cleared things up. What I don't understand is *why* I'm able to do this. I'm using the TableView template in XCode, so the "freebies" mean that I get to do things I wouldn't know how to implement otherwise. Say I were implementing this code in the Delegate (if that would be appropriate?) or another class, how would I access the tableView then? Thanks again!

Comment: @Murdock just added an edit to the answer to (try to) answer your first question.  As to why self.tableView works.  The object the template created for you is a subclass UITableViewController, which handles creating the actual UITableView automagically and sets its tableView property to the UITableView it creates.  Because your view controller inherits from UITableViewController, you can get to it's properties using the self variable, just like you can get to any of your own properties...

Comment: ... if you were in another object, but you had a UITableViewController in a variable, say like this: (UITableViewController *mainTVC = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]), you would get to the UITableView created by that UITableViewController by calling mainTVC.tableView.  Does that clear things up at all?

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks a bunch for the more in-depth explanation. It was very helpful, really helped me get a better handle on self. notation, retaining variables, etc. And yes, I agree, the dot notation is one of the least intuitive aspects of obj-c I've encountered so far. It's funny because at first I thought dot notation was going to be both convenient and intuitive "Hey, it's shorthand! How nice for coding!" but I'm realizing that the use of it is rather non-trivial, and it has unexpected behaviors. Anyway, all part of the learning process. Thanks again for your extensive reply.